# Regression on price or price difference

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am trying to predict the price movement for high-frequency trading purpose, but so far I did not get a lot of success with just predicting the price directly.

[image]

We can see that there's a little trend, but it is not that good. What do you think about applying regression on price difference between times t+1 and t instead of the price itself?

Here is my list of features

```
FEATURES = [

            ## Ask Price ##
            "AskPrice1", "AskPrice2", "AskPrice3", "AskPrice4", "AskPrice5",      

           ## Ask Quantity ##
            "AskQty1", "AskQty2", "AskQty3", "AskQty4", "AskQty5", 

            ## Bid Price ##
            "BidPrice1", "BidPrice2", "BidPrice3", "BidPrice4", "BidPrice5",

           ## Bid Quantity ##
            "BidQty1", "BidQty2", "BidQty3", "BidQty4", "BidQty5",

           ## Cancel Buy Price ##
            #"CancelBuyPrice1", "CancelBuyPrice10", "CancelBuyPrice11", "CancelBuyPrice12",
            #"CancelBuyPrice13", "CancelBuyPrice14", "CancelBuyPrice15", "CancelBuyPrice16", "CancelBuyPrice17",
            #"CancelBuyPrice18", "CancelBuyPrice19", "CancelBuyPrice2", "CancelBuyPrice20", "CancelBuyPrice3", "CancelBuyPrice4",
            #"CancelBuyPrice5", "CancelBuyPrice6", "CancelBuyPrice7", "CancelBuyPrice8", "CancelBuyPrice9", 

           ## Cancel Quantity ##
            "CancelBuyQty1",
            "CancelBuyQty10", "CancelBuyQty11", "CancelBuyQty12", "CancelBuyQty13", "CancelBuyQty14", "CancelBuyQty15",
            "CancelBuyQty16", "CancelBuyQty17", "CancelBuyQty18", "CancelBuyQty19", "CancelBuyQty2", "CancelBuyQty20",   
            "CancelBuyQty3", "CancelBuyQty4", "CancelBuyQty5", "CancelBuyQty6", "CancelBuyQty7", "CancelBuyQty8", "CancelBuyQty9",

            ## Cancel Sell Price ##
            #"CancelSellPrice1", "CancelSellPrice10", "CancelSellPrice11", "CancelSellPrice12", "CancelSellPrice13", 
            #"CancelSellPrice14", "CancelSellPrice15", "CancelSellPrice16", "CancelSellPrice17", "CancelSellPrice18",
            #"CancelSellPrice19", "CancelSellPrice2", "CancelSellPrice20", "CancelSellPrice3", "CancelSellPrice4",
            #"CancelSellPrice5", "CancelSellPrice6", "CancelSellPrice7", "CancelSellPrice8", "CancelSellPrice9",

            ## Cancel Sell Quantity ##
            "CancelSellQty1", "CancelSellQty10", "CancelSellQty11", "CancelSellQty12", "CancelSellQty13", "CancelSellQty14",
            "CancelSellQty15", "CancelSellQty16", "CancelSellQty17", "CancelSellQty18", "CancelSellQty19", "CancelSellQty2",
            "CancelSellQty20", "CancelSellQty3", "CancelSellQty4", "CancelSellQty5", "CancelSellQty6", "CancelSellQty7",
            "CancelSellQty8", "CancelSellQty9", 

            ## Limit Buy Price ##
            #"LimitBuyPrice1", "LimitBuyPrice10", "LimitBuyPrice11", "LimitBuyPrice12",   
            #"LimitBuyPrice13", "LimitBuyPrice14", "LimitBuyPrice15", "LimitBuyPrice16", "LimitBuyPrice17", "LimitBuyPrice18",
            #"LimitBuyPrice19", "LimitBuyPrice2", "LimitBuyPrice20", "LimitBuyPrice3", "LimitBuyPrice4", "LimitBuyPrice5",    
            #"LimitBuyPrice6", "LimitBuyPrice7", "LimitBuyPrice8", "LimitBuyPrice9", 

            ## Limit Buy Quantity ##
            "LimitBuyQty1", "LimitBuyQty10",
            "LimitBuyQty17", "LimitBuyQty18", "LimitBuyQty19", "LimitBuyQty2", "LimitBuyQty20", "LimitBuyQty3", "LimitBuyQty4",
            "LimitBuyQty11", "LimitBuyQty12", "LimitBuyQty13", "LimitBuyQty14", "LimitBuyQty15", "LimitBuyQty16",
            "LimitBuyQty5", "LimitBuyQty6", "LimitBuyQty7", "LimitBuyQty8", "LimitBuyQty9", 

            ## Limit Sell Price ##
            #"LimitSellPrice1",   
            #"LimitSellPrice10", "LimitSellPrice11", "LimitSellPrice12", "LimitSellPrice13", "LimitSellPrice14",
            #"LimitSellPrice15", "LimitSellPrice16", "LimitSellPrice17", "LimitSellPrice18", "LimitSellPrice19",
            #"LimitSellPrice2", "LimitSellPrice20", "LimitSellPrice3", "LimitSellPrice4", "LimitSellPrice5", 
            #"LimitSellPrice6", "LimitSellPrice7", "LimitSellPrice8", "LimitSellPrice9", 

            ## Limit Sell Quantity ##
            "LimitSellQty1", "LimitSellQty10",
            "LimitSellQty11", "LimitSellQty12", "LimitSellQty13", "LimitSellQty14", "LimitSellQty15", "LimitSellQty16",
            "LimitSellQty17", "LimitSellQty18", "LimitSellQty19", "LimitSellQty2", "LimitSellQty20", "LimitSellQty3",     
            "LimitSellQty4", "LimitSellQty5", "LimitSellQty6", "LimitSellQty7", "LimitSellQty8", "LimitSellQty9",

            ## Others ##
            "midprice"]
            #"MarketBuyQty", "MarketSellQty", "VWAP-midprice", "midprice"]
            # "BestAsk", "BestAskDiff", "BestBid", "BestBidDiff"]
```

Answer (score 3):

The debate on price/return/difference is quite common when building a trading model. You have to ask yourself, am I interested in price level for t+1 or am I interested in whether t+1 price is less/greater than t price? If your goal is the former, predict price. If your goal is the latter, predict return. However you could use either to predict each outcome:

price level t+1  = return prediction t+1 * price t

return t+1 = price prediction t+1 / price t

In trading it's all about monetizing the signal so take that into account too. Generally, predicting returns/differences is the more frequented path. This is because it is easier to monetize, e.g. long/short based on positive or negative signal. I've tried to predict price and I have never succeeded in getting profitable accuracy; I now predict returns/differences.

As far as specifically answering your question, building a model on price difference **might** work better. This is because you are making the series potential more stationary which might be easier for a model to approximate than a trending + seasonal + noisy time series. From the looks of the plot you have provided, the model is falling into a common trap where it predicts t+1 = t. This mirroring effect is pretty common in forecasting time series with machine learning, especially neural networks. In regards to your features, are you scaling them? If you are using ANN/DNN you should scale both input and output vectors.

Ultimately, testing is king when it comes to trading system development, test both! However, if you are set on predict price I can point you to a few articles that do this with some success. Please let me know and I will look for the links.

**Update**

Here are some useful links to white papers :

They use daily data in this article, but experience the same issues as you. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-not-to-use-machine-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-avoiding-the-pitfalls-19f9d7adf424

http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2017/final-reports/5241098.pdf

Comment: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8747/price-movement-forecasting-issue - You will have a bit more details on that question. You can try to transpose your answer on that question instead. Yeah, few links should be nice. Btw, we applied differentiation on the features as well and we use 20 to 30 seconds to try predicting t+1.